# When use pyinstaller package a pyqt5 program to exe in window7 it running error

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Failed to execute script pyi_rth_multiprocessing[image]

Comment: Could you post the python code you were trying to package?

Comment: Use pyinstaller again without ``-w``

Comment: This is a PyInstaller bug. It's not related to Qt. You can find the ticket on GitHub if you look